# Excel Copy Paste Activity in UiPath Freezes Without any action being done

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

In UiPath, I use `Copy Sheet` to bring a sheet with all the formats to another excel. Now I use `Copy Paste Range` for a range like `A:I`. This simply freezes, no error, execution seems to continue but nothing happens after several minutes of waiting (it should continue with another copy paste of about similar size to different sheet for what it’s worth). Memory and CPU are not maxed out. Once I stop the bot, I have to end the excel application from task manager to edit the excel.

`Read Range` and `Write Range` are not used because, I need the format to be maintained.

Comment: This sounds to me like the typical issue with Excel workbooks. I also having those from time to time. When you run into this issue, could you try to kill the Excel process manually via Task manager? What happens when u do that?

Comment: @kwoxer : Yes, I end the excel process and then only i will be able to open that excel to make some changes. Is there any alternate method instead of Copy Paste to retain the format of the values we copy and paste?

Comment: Why not copy the whole file? Sorry I never tried to copy a cell into another cell.

Comment: First process  I did was copying the complete sheet to another workbook and then copy paste activity to paste those values into the desired template.

Comment: Personally I haven't tried this yet so can't help but I would suggest raising an issue with the product. If it is a valid issue with the activity package then it must be looked at.

Comment: Please show the workflow so that it could be replicated in order to diagnose/resolve the issue